# Not able to update owner and file permission on files mounted on azure fileshare in AKS pod

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-files

I have an AKS cluster on which i am running a pod.
I am using dynamic pvc with the cluster and mounting it on my application's config path.

The problem is when I use hostPath based volume for my application, it works fine as application is able to store files with the appropriate permissions and ownership in the hostPath based volume .
But with using azure file share, as far I have understood there seems to be a concept of single user and same file permission on the azure file share (which is configured using storage class)

What I want is for the azure fileshare to not interfere with the application's ability to modify the file permissions or if there is  a way to bypass this.

I feel like I am missing something.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure File Share does not support manipulation of permissions within the mounted volume. Operations such as `chown` and `chmod` will not work with CIFS implementation of the SMB protocol.

You will either need to create separate volumes for each permissions variation required, or select a different storage class/volume type for your volume.

Comment: Thanku for the clarification