# Bitnami Postgresql-ha and AKS storage error

Tags: postgresql, azure-aks, bitnami

I am attempting to deploy instances of the Bitnami Postgresql-ha chart on an AKS cluster, however I am having issues with persistence. You should be able to multi-attach an Azure disk to multiple pods, however the controller complains that its unable to provision so I am using an Azure fileshare. I added a few `mountOptions` to the `StorageClass` for permissions to adhere to the Bitnami chart, and I also enabled `image.debug` on `postgresql` to get more information. I do not think that this is an issue (related to this error), but I am using Istio.

Here is my `StorageClass`:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azurefile-csi
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0750
  - file_mode=0750
  - uid=1001
  - gid=1001
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - nosharesock
  - actimeo=30
```

I have the `replicaCount` set to 3, these are the logs from the first pod:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /bitnami/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
2023-10-15 19:06:59.371 UTC [139] LOG:  could not link file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.139" to "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": Operation not supported
2023-10-15 19:06:59.392 UTC [139] FATAL:  could not open file "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data"
running bootstrap script ...
```

I have read that Postgres needs to create some hard links and that Azure file does not support this, is this true? I have read a good amount on this issue with no luck, help please :)

Answer (score 0):

> “could not link file “pg_wal/xlogtemp.139” to
> “pg_wal/000000010000000000000001”: Operation not supported.”

As we can see from the error, PostgreSQL does not work with Azure file. This is because PostgreSQL requires hard links in the Azure File directory, and since Azure File does not support hard links the pod fails to start.

To **fix** this, you can use a different storage backend for PostgreSQL, such as Azure Disks as Azure Disks support hard links.

Create a PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) that uses the `azure-disk` provisioner as below-

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgresql-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi  #choice of storage size 
  storageClassName: azure-disk
```

[image]

Create a PostgreSQL deployment that uses this PVC as below:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgresql
spec:
  replicas: 3 #choice of replicas
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgresql
        image: bitnami/postgresql:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgresql-data
          mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: postgresql-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgresql-data
```

[image]

And finally deploy the PostgreSQL-HA chart using bitnami Helm chart as below-

```bash
helm install my-release bitnami/postgresql-ha
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can also refer below documents:
[Postgress on AKS](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/548)
[Postgresql on Azure Kubernetes with data persistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66860101/postgres-on-azure-kubernetes-volume-permission-error)
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-overview#secure-transfer)